# C++ Qt QString replace double backslash with one

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I have a QString with following content:

> "MXTP24\\x00\\x00\\xF4\\xF9\\x80\r\n"

I want it to become:

> "MXTP24\x00\x00\xF4\xF9\x80\r\n"

I need to replace the "\x" to "\x" so that I can start parsing the values. But the following code, which I think should do the job is not doing anything as I get the same string before and after:

```
qDebug() << "BEFORE: " << data;
data = data.replace("\\\\x", "\\x", Qt::CaseSensitivity::CaseInsensitive);
qDebug() << "AFTER: " << data;
```

Here, no change!

[image]

Then I tried like this:

```
data = data.replace("\\x", "\x", Qt::CaseSensitivity::CaseInsensitive);
```

Then compiler complaines that `\x used with no following hex digits!`

any ideas?

Comment: It does work for me. How is `data` assigned?

Comment: *replace the "\x" to "\x"* , what?

Comment: So *data* is a QString?

Comment: @hyde Well, first it is QByteArray but I do like QString data(byteArray)

Comment: To convert 8 bit char data to unicode QString, it's generally better to be explicit about encoding, so depending on that, better do *QString data(QString::fromLatin1(byteArray));*, replace Latin1 with right encoding *fromUtf8* (check the docs) if necessary (for 7 bit ASCII text,  most codecs are fine).

Comment: Also, consider keeping the text as QByteArray at least for processing, unless you really need unicode text (eg. for GUI widgets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's look at what this piece of code does:

```
data.replace("\\\\x", "\\x", ....
```

First string becomes `\\x` in compiled code, and is used as regular expression. In reqular expression, backslash is special, and needs to be escaped with another backslash to mean actual single backslash character, and your regexp does just this. 4 backslashes in C+n string literal regexp means matching single literal backslash in target text. So your reqular expression matches literal 2-character string `\x`.

Then you replace it. Replacement isn't a reqular expression, so backslash doesn't need double escaping here, so you end up using literal 2-char replacement string `\x`, which is same as what you matched, so even if there is a match, nothing changes.

---

However, this is not your problem, your problem is how `qDebug()` prints strings. It prints them escaped. That `\"` at start of output means just plain double quote, 1 char, in the actual string because double quote is escaped. And those `\\` also are single backslash char, because literal backslash is also escaped (because it is the escape char and has special meaning for the next char).

So it seems you don't need to do any search replace at all, just remove it.

Try printing the QString in one of these ways to get is shown literally:

```
std::cout << data << std::endl;

qDebug() << data.toLatin1().constData();
```

Comment: Pleae check my update, I have noted what I want the result to be. simply put I want \\x to become \x

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer and extra comments!

Answer (score 0):

[QRegularExpression](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qregularexpression.html) can be used to help provide special character replacements, like so:

```
QString path = "string\\with\\backslashes";
path.replace(QRegularExpression("\\"), "\");
```

Output:

```
"string\with\backslashes"
```

Hope this helps.